# What are the functions of the callbacks in the commerce payment method info hook?

Tags: hooks, commerce

Can someone explain me the differences, maybe with some examples, between the callbacks in the hook_commerce_payment_method_info()?

The callbacks are these: settings_form, submit_form, submit_form_validate, submit_form_submit, redirect_form, redirect_form_validate, redirect_form_submit.

I'm trying to implement a payment module and I need to know how to use the callback of the above-mentioned hook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find Contributed Modules API Documentation in http://drupalcontrib.org/ portal.

Please find link to above hook documentation [hook_commerce_payment_method_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/hook_commerce_payment_method_info/7) .

Callbacks Documentation links below...

[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_settings_form()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_settings_form/7)
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form/7) 
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form_validate()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form_validate/7)
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form_submit()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_submit_form_submit/7) 
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form/7)
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form_validate()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form_validate/7)
[CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form_submit()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form_submit/7)

Check out [commerce_payment_example](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!modules!commerce_payment_example.module/7) module to find out how to write a payment method for more information.

Comment: Thanks Anil for your reply. I found by myself the documentation that you posted me, but actually there is only and example on the "submit callbacks" and the api have very few information... I'd need more documentation on these. Thanks

Comment: and what is the difference between "submit form" and "submit form submission"?

Answer (score 1):

I found this example of a callback, which puts up a little form to enter a card number:

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce_kickstart!modules!commerce_kickstart!commerce_kickstart_payment!commerce_kickstart_payment.module/7

```
    function commerce_kickstart_payment_submit_form($payment_method, $pane_values, $checkout_pane, $order) {
      module_load_include('inc', 'commerce_payment', 'includes/commerce_payment.credit_card');
      $fields = array(
        'type' => array(
          'visa',
          'mastercard',
          'amex',
        ),
      );
      $default = array(
        'number' => '4111111111111111',
      );
      return commerce_payment_credit_card_form($fields, $default);
    }
```